# How to get data from JSON file and put into my Postgres SQL tables using node-postgres

Tags: node.js, postgresql, node-postgres

I have got a Json file that looks like below example

```
[
  {
    Title: "abc",
    Author: "abc",
    Genre: "abc"
  },
]
```

I am creating a full stack app and I using node-postgres and Elephant SQL for my project
I've created the table that has the above columns I want to know how can populate my table with my JSON data

I've imported the JSON file and have tried the below

```
export async function insert () {
    
    
    return await pool.query (
        `INSERT INTO books (
          Title,
          Author,
          Genre) (
          SELECT  Title, Author, Genre
          FROM json_populate_recordset(NULL::books, $1::JSON)
        );`,
        [JSON.stringify(books)]
      );
}
```

I get an error as below
error: null value in column "title" of relation "books" violates not-null constraint

I've got value in all my properties in JSON file but it keeps giving me this error, can someone please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you [quote your identifiers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS), Postgres normalises them to lowercase. You can see this in the error message, the column is actually named `title` not `Title`. You can change your query to

```
INSERT INTO books ("Title", "Author", "Genre")
SELECT "Title", "Author", "Genre"
FROM json_populate_recordset(NULL::books, $1::JSON);
```

to get a better error message - that you also need to change your table definition. However, using capitalised identifiers in Postgres is an antipattern (it is unconventional and just makes everything harder), so better avoid it. Rather use the SQL you have, or write

```
INSERT INTO books (title, author, genre)
SELECT title, author, genre
FROM json_populate_recordset(NULL::books, $1::JSON);
```

and change your JSON data to

```
[
  {
    "title": "abc",
    "author": "abc",
    "genre": "abc"
  }
]
```